# Non-equidistant axis labels

Tags: r, plot

Does anybody know how to adjust the labels in a base plot to NOT be equidistant? I have tick marks at different distance from each other and want the labels to center between these. The `axis` function's `hadj` argument only takes one value.

Comment: Can you share some data and existing code?

Comment: The `at` parameter of the axis is used to position both tick marks and labels. The hadj is only useful when you want the labels to be off-center from the tick marks.

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust, you indirectly led me to my solution. I realized that could used the `axis` function for the tick marks and the draw lines with `abline` for the actual ticks (which in my case span the whole plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so that this question has a spelled-out answer (albeit a slightly different one than suggested in the comments):

```
ticks <- c(0, 1, 3, 6, 10)
labels <- c("one", "two", "three", "four") # one fewer than ticks
label.positions <- ticks[-1] - diff(ticks) / 2
plot(1:10, 1:10, xlim=c(-1, 11), axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
axis(1, at=ticks, labels=FALSE)
axis(1, at=label.positions, labels=labels, tick=FALSE)
```

[image: screenshot of plot with unequally spaced axis ticks and axis labels centered between ticks]

Comment: Thanks, that's also an obvious solution.